# Accelerometer works in first game, but goes crazy in the second

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, accelerometer

I'm creating a game where a player will control a falling sprite with the accelerometer X axis and an impulse is added when the user taps on the screen. In my current code when I run the game, it works okay and then once the player dies and tries again the sprite goes crazy and just flies of the screen. Can someone help please...

```
class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var score = 0

    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var labelHolder = SKSpriteNode()

    var background = SKSpriteNode()

    let playerGroup:UInt32 = 1
    let objectGroup:UInt32 = 2
    let gapGroup:UInt32 = 0 << 3
    let boundary:UInt32 = 4
    var movingObjects = SKNode()

    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var destX:CGFloat = 0.0
    var gameOver = 0

    var currentX: CGFloat?



    let greenPlayer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Image/Players/greenPlayer.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.physicsBody!.friction = 0
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-0.0, -0.8)


        self.addChild(labelHolder)

        scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height - 140)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)

        //self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.addChild(movingObjects)

        let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image/TempBG.png")

        background=SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.size.width = self.frame.width
        background.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(background)

        greenPlayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: greenPlayer.size.height/2)
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerGroup
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectGroup
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup
        greenPlayer.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boundary
        //self.greenPlayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

        self.greenPlayer.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        greenPlayer.zPosition = 5
        self.addChild(greenPlayer)

        currentX = self.greenPlayer.position.x


        //if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler:{ data, error in

            if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
                self.destX = self.currentX! + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
            }
            else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
                self.destX = self.currentX! + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
            }
        })

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("makeDodges"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func makeDodges() {


        if(gameOver == 0){

            let gapWidth = greenPlayer.size.width * 3
            let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.width / 2)
            let dodgeOffSet = CGFloat(movementAmount) - (self.frame.size.width / 4)

            let moveDodges = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            let removeDodges = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let moveAndRemoveDodges = SKAction.sequence([moveDodges, removeDodges])

            let dodge1Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image/Dodge.png")
            let dodge1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: dodge1Texture)
            dodge1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + dodge1.size.width/2 + gapWidth/2 + dodgeOffSet, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - self.frame.size.height)
            dodge1.runAction(moveDodges)
            dodge1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: dodge1.size)
            dodge1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            dodge1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            dodge1.zPosition = 10
            movingObjects.addChild(dodge1)

            let dodge2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image/Dodge.png")
            let dodge2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: dodge2Texture)
            dodge2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - dodge2.size.width/2 - gapWidth/2 + dodgeOffSet , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - self.frame.size.height)

            dodge2.runAction(moveDodges)
            dodge2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: dodge2.size)
            dodge2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            dodge2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            dodge2.zPosition = 10
            movingObjects.addChild(dodge2)

            let gap = SKNode()
            gap.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + dodgeOffSet , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - self.frame.size.height)
            gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(dodge1.size.height, gapWidth))
            gap.runAction(moveAndRemoveDodges)
            gap.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            gap.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup
            gap.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gapGroup
            gap.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(gap)

        }
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == gapGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == gapGroup {

            score++

            print(score)

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

        } else {

            if gameOver == 0 {

                gameOver = 1
                movingObjects.speed = 0

                let scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
            }
        }


    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if(gameOver == 0) {

            greenPlayer.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            greenPlayer.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 50))

        } else {

            score = 0
            scoreLabel.text = "0"
            movingObjects.removeAllChildren()
            self.greenPlayer.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            greenPlayer.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            labelHolder.removeAllChildren()
            gameOver = 0
            movingObjects.speed = 1
            currentX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)

        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 1)
        self.greenPlayer.runAction(action)

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the scene object after completing a level, you have to remove it, or call some method from it object to reload?

Comment: @alex_p im just changing back to my home scene by a transition

Answer (score 0):

You never stop and remove the old motion manager queue, so your old scene will never die, thus causing your problems.

Add `motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates();motionManager = nil;` at the point you want to destroy your old scene,  If you are not destroying your old scene, and just resetting your data, then just add `motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates();` to the point where you are going to reset your scene.

Comment: Ive done this and it has made it less crazy but on the second game it floats away a lot more either side so im unable to control the sprite, Thank You!

Comment: check to see if the block is being updated more than once on the second run,  if it is, call startAccelerometerUpdates() instead on the second run.  Also, check to make sure that NSOperationQueue.currentQueue() is not running on your main thread,  apple does not recommend running it on the main thread

Comment: Thank you, i have called startAccelerometerUpdates() but it still does the same problem, the sprite moves the way i want it to but as if there is friction or gravity affecting it as it just floats from side to side very slowly and not very fast response times. Also how do i check if NSOperationQueue.currentQueue() is running in the main thread? sorry im fairly new to xcode

Comment: Are the results different each play through or the same? Also, you do know that let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 1) means that everytime you call this, it will take 1 second to go from current spot to destination,  so if you tilt slightly, it will take 1 second to go a small distance, if you tilt a lot, it will take 1 second to move alot.  The way you are righting your code,  do not use the moveTo action,  just set the position manually of your sprite. To check for mainqueue use if NSOperationQueue.currentQueue() == NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(){print("On Main");}